# Error in calling interpolation plugin for IDW in QGIS python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, interpolation

I wanted to call the interpolation plugin for IDW from python plugin and displays its output on QGIS desktop.

I am able to call the function but the output displayed on QGIS qgis desktop with NAN NAN values.

Below are the lines which I have used to generate the output. OS:UBUNTU

```
import qgis.core
import qgis.analysis
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

layer_data = qgis.analysis.QgsInterpolator.LayerData()

layer_data.vectorLayer = layer
layer_data.zCoordInterpolation=False 
layer_data.InterpolationAttribute = 10 #attribute index starting from 0
layer_data.mInputType = 1

tin_interpolator = qgis.analysis.QgsIDWInterpolator([layer_data])

export_path ="/home/usr/Documents/After Krigging/2.asc"
rect = layer.extent()
output = qgis.analysis.QgsGridFileWriter(tin_interpolator,export_path,rect,300, 300, 1015.33333,728.66667)
output.writeFile(True)  

iface.addRasterLayer(export_path, "interpolation_output")
```

The image below is the output I got after running the above lines.
Can Anyone suggest me what I should do to solve this problem?

[image: Output]

It generate the file 1.asc but it have all values as -9999 which is incorrect, can anyone suggest what I need to change in the function call to make sure this kind of data is not generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class definition later got changed.
Just change the layer_data.InterpolationAttribute = 10 to layer_data.interpolationAttribute = 10 it will work.
Changing "I" to "i".